# React Hook: Can't access states in the function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am facing a problem with custom hook. I can't access states in the function. For example: **data, error, loading**

It is showing an error: **"loading is not defined"**. I know that variables is out of scope but I want to use loading, error.

```
export const useLikeTrack = track => {

  const { addFavoriteTrack } = useTrackContext();
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false)

  const likeTrack = (params) => {
    const { data, error, loading } = useAxios({
        axiosInstance: myApiAxiosInstance,
        url: `tracks/${track["id"]}/likes`,
        method: "POST"
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading && data) {
      addFavoriteTrack(track);
      setSuccess(true);
    }
  }, [loading, data]);
  return { loading, error, success, likeTrack };
};

export default function TrackItem({ track }) {

  const {success, loading, error, likeTrack} = useLikeTrack(track.id)
  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <button className="" onClick={likeTrack}>Like
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can you help me fix it ? I am using **useAxios** from this: https://github.com/angelle-sw/use-axios-client

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I think you have to do `onClick={likeTrack}` instead of `onClick={()=>likeTrack}`

Comment: @ShubhamVerma, Hi it is showing: **loading is not defined**

Comment: You are declaring `data`, `loading` and `error` in your `axios` endpoint call. Not within your hook scope.

Comment: @Wong I don't see likeTrack function calling? from where you call this function.

Comment: @dev_junwen, I am using custom hook (useAxios) from other people. How to make it within my hook scope. Or I have to write my own hook instead useAxios ?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma, you can see in the end of question   <button className="" onClick={likeTrack}>Like
      </button>

Comment: @Wong I think you dont need to this. You need to fetch directly from axios. Can you put your code at codesandbox?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma, I will ping you after putting my code to codesandbox

Comment: Can you show your `useAxios()` hook?

Comment: Also you should never call hooks inside of nested functions: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: @oemera, I am using useAxios from this: https://github.com/angelle-sw/use-axios-client

Comment: don't use `useAxios` for event handlers, it's no good for that (it's good for fetching data unconditionally after mounting a component). use normal `axios.post(...)` in event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Aprillion suggested in the comments, you should use the normal axios package to create a request in a handler, like so:

```
import axios from "axios";

...
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const likeTrack = (params) => {
    setLoading(true);
    myApiAxiosInstance.post(`tracks/${track["id"]}/likes`)
    .then(response => {
       setLoading(false);
       setData(response.data)
    })
  }
...
```

However, if you really want to use a hook, try out the [axios-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-hooks) library instead. Beside the fact that it has way more recent npm-downloads than your package, you can call an axios request *manually* which is basically what you need here.

First, install the library with  `npm install axios axios-hooks`

Then adjust your code like so:

```
import axios from "axios";

...
   const [{ data, error, loading }, execute] = useAxios({
        axiosInstance: myApiAxiosInstance,
        url: `tracks/${track["id"]}/likes`,
        method: "POST"
      },
      {
        manual: true // This is important, otherwise your request would be fired automatically after your component mounted
   });

  const likeTrack = (params) => {
    execute(); // execute the request manually
  }
...
```

Note how I wrapped the `useAxios` return value with an array and added `execute` at the end. With `execute()` you can trigger the request manually. Also, don't forget to configure your request to only fire manually, as in the example.

**source:** https://github.com/simoneb/axios-hooks#example

Comment: Awesome. This is what I need. :) I will try both

Answer (score 3):

`if (!loading && data) {`

There is no `loading` nor `data` declared in that scope.  They are inside another function called `likeTrack()`

To be more specific:

```
const likeTrack = (params) => {
  const { data, error, loading } = useAxios({
// ...
  }
}
```

those vars (`data, error, loading`) are **not** accessible outside of that function

Comment: Yes, I know. I want to use **loading** and **data** in the TrackItem component.

Comment: yeah then you need to use them inside the hook first.  you are trying to return missing vars

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're passing `track.id` instead of `track` to your custom hook.